# Is multipoint datatype in MySQL the best way to store a list of (lat, long)'s?

Tags: mysql, database, geopoints

I want to store a grid which is nothing but a list of latitude and longitudes in MySQL. From MySQL documentation i realised multipoint datatype is one way to do this, is my understanding correct? Also what would be the best possible way to do this?

Comment: "A grid" basically means a bunch of independent *points*? Then you should probably store them as individual rows with one point each?

Comment: It's a 'way'. Does it matter if it's the best possible way?

Comment: @deceze Yes, but multipoint datatype is meant to satisfy similar use cases wherein I won't need individual rows.

Comment: @Strawberry I was wondering whether multipoint would cause any problem while storing lat,longs. As in even a small change like 1000th decimal change to latitude will actually change the location. I hope using multipoint does not create such issues.